# SIM card, saving space, contacts

Tags: alcatel-one-touch-idol-s

Does it take up less space to save contacts to my SIM card or device? My phone only has 8MB and I wanna do whatever saves more space.

Comment: Unless you have several hundred or thousands of contacts, their space usage is minimal. I have about 300 contacts and it takes up 40KB of space. Besides, on the SIM you can only store name and number, no additional information, and most newer SIMs allow for 250-500 contacts.

Comment: In addition to that, you must have a typo in your question: I never heard of an Android device with just 8 **MB** of storage. You probably mean **GB,** do you? And do you know how much space a SIM card has? Depending on its type, [between **8 kB** and 256 **kB**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subscriber_identity_module#Data). Now compare how much you can save by moving things there :)

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to store important contacts to SIM card so that even if you change phones for some reason the contacts remain with you.

Doing this you can distribute the amount of memory, taken up by contacts, between SIM and phone memory.

Answer (score 0):

**Does it take up less space to save contacts to my SIM card or device?**

- The difference will not be remarkable (few Kilos) when you have no contact pictures.
- Try to sync your contacts to to your Google Contacts.

**My phone only has 8MB and I wanna do whatever saves more space.**

- Your phone has 4GB ROM, you have to move your unnecessary files to MicroSD Card(s) to gain more space and optimize your phone performance.
- There are many applications used to clean junk files from your device, like [CleanMaster](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cleanmaster.mguard)